# Place Single quotes inside the String using Mule 4 Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

We are using Mule 4 (runtime 4.3.0) and Dataweave 2.0

Database expects the queries to be like

`Select id from table where firstName = 'test-from-text`';

Value for the first name comes from query params firstName. We are constructing the SQL queries in mule-like below:-

```
<ee:transform doc:name="firstName" doc:id="1e151bed-d1c4-4af2-b2f6-91f9cbf1f89d">
                    <ee:message>
                    </ee:message>
                    <ee:variables>
                        <ee:set-variable variableName="firstName"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
        output application/java
        ---
        attributes.queryParams.firstName]]></ee:set-variable></ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Sql Query" doc:id="765c361e-e400-45ad-810a-c504169eb4ad" >
                <ee:message >
                </ee:message>
                <ee:variables >
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="sqlQuery" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    'SELECT id
    FROM table WHERE firstName =' ++vars.firstName
    </ee:set-variable>
                </ee:variables>
            </ee:transform>
```

We pass the vars.sqlQuery into the database connector. The above code generates queries like "select id from the table where firstName = test-from-text" . Database expects queries to be like

`Select id from table where firstName = 'test-from-text`';

Note:

we need to construct the query in variables like here (reason: a lot of condition around it). we do have a column like dates where we need to mention as quote surrounded.

In above the first name contains "from" which is a database reserved keyword. It works when we query in sql editor with quotes surrounded.

Questions:
How do surround the vars.firstName with single quotes in the vars.SqlQuery String

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes for the string literals so the single quote is just another character:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
"SELECT id
FROM table WHERE firstName = '" ++ vars.firstName ++ "'"
```

Alternatively you could just escape the single quotes but it looks more confusing:

```js
'SELECT id
FROM table WHERE firstName = \'' ++ vars.firstName ++ '\''
```